# Unable to access file in hard drive using Apache Tomcat server

Tags: java, file, tomcat, web-applications

I'm developing local-only JSP application using Apache Tomcat server. I would like to put a promotion videos on my intro page, but I don't want to move them to webapp folder or anywhere else.

The promotion videos are located:

- E:\data\videos\2018...

But writing a JSP/HTML like this wont launch the video, but however it works off-server (launching html from desktop for example, so the path may not be issue?)

```
<video src="file:///E:/data/videos/2018/promotion1.mp4" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local file links from remote resources are disabled by almost all browsers by default. There are certain possibilities to overcome that, e.g.:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/opening-links-to-local-files-file/16449/2

To access your static media files from remote page you need to configure your Tomcat server as described here: http://teknosrc.com/access-local-files-static-content-images-videos-media-files-outside-web-application-system-apache-tomcat-server/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't think that that's a browser issue, I can play the video off-server when opening html file in browser. As I mentioned in the question, the server is and will stay local only.

Comment: This is what I'm saying. Browser will allow you to open local files only off-server when opening html file as file:///. But will not allow to do the same when you open it as `http://localhost...`

Comment: Oh sorry, now I understand it properly. So if there is no way to achieve this, I have to deploy the server to the videos folder I guess. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link on how to configure tomcat to resolve it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

solution: 
a.) make sure your server is on the same system where the media files are.

b.) If so, you have to create a folder (ex. media) in your application folder inside /src/main/webapp/ and have to put all media files inside a media folder. After that, you can surely access the media files through a server.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, that's not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to move the files anywhere if possible.